# Slick Carousel - how to change active slide position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Hi I need to move the current active slide to the right a bit with `padding-left`. Doing so makes the slider jump a bit on each next slide.

How to fix this behavior?

https://jsfiddle.net/ezy50jd2/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="slick-center">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x150">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x150">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slick-slide{
  width: 300px;
}
.slick-center .slick-current{
  padding-left: 90px;/*this makes slides jump*/
}
```

Setup:

```
$(function () {
    $('.slick-center').slick({
        infinite: true,
        autoplay: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '180px',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        speed: 400,
        dots: false,
        prevArrow: false,
        nextArrow: false,
        variableWidth: true
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of having the padding on the 'current item'?

Comment: good question, because i need to add an element to the left of each current active slide. So the current slide needs to be pushed right.

Comment: Just asking, because there could be a better approach to your problem, if you'd provide more markup on what this ***element*** is.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the transform attribute. You might even add transition effect for smoother animation.

```
 transform: translateX(90px);  
 transition: 1s ease-in-out;
```

A fork of your fiddle with the implementation
https://jsfiddle.net/nh4qucdp/25/

Comment: Hi Aditya, Thanks so much but there's still a jumping effect after 3 slides, even with transition which really shows up on my live version. Could it be a bug with slick slider?